# Free form input in feedback form not displayed on facebook messager

Tags: facebook, messaging, feedback

I am developing the customer feedback feature on facebook messager by using Free form input. After that I tested on the web browser(Firefox & Chrome) the free form input is not displayed but on the IOS/Android messenger application it works as expected.
please help me to fix.
thanks all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdhIb.png)

```
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "xxxxx"
  },
  "message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "customer_feedback",
        "title": "Vincent",
        "subtitle": "Let Original Coast Clothing know how they are doing by answering two questions",
        "button_title": "Rate Experience",
        "feedback_screens": [
          {
            "questions": [
              {
                "id": "f0b17e00_a0b6_4673_aee8_cee56efcaab2",
                "type": "csat",
                "title": "Feedback",
                "score_label": "neg_pos",
                "score_option": "five_stars",
                "follow_up": {
                  "type": "FREE_FORM",
                  "placeholder": "Give additional feedback"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "business_privacy": {
          "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "expires_in_days": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to the free form input display on feedback form.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sirj7.png